# Finding distinct values of a column from a sheet of excel file in python

Tags: excel, pandas, python-3.8

> **How can I find the first column's distict values from sheet3 ?**

```
import sys
import pandas as pd


excel_file = "dataset.xlsx"
datasets = pd.ExcelFile(excel_file)

sheet0 = pd.read_excel(datasets, 'Title Sheet')
sheet3 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=3, index_col=0)
sheet4 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=4, index_col=0)
sheet1 = pd.read_excel(excel_file, sheet_name=1, index_col=0)

customer_data = pd.concat([sheet3, sheet4, sheet1])
```

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? `unq = sheet3.iloc[:,0].unique()` and then `print(unq)`

Comment: Yeah, absolutely ! If I want to count them, just count by loop or is there any direct method ?  Thanks for the help.

Comment: `unq = sheet3.iloc[:,0].nunique()`

Answer (score 1):

To get the unique values of the specific sheet, you can do:

```
unq = sheet3.iloc[:,0].unique()
print(unq)
```

To get the count of unique values, you can do:

```
unq = sheet3.iloc[:,0].nunique()
print(unq)
```